# What to do in case of Lost/Delayed baggage

Tags: luggage, compensation, air-canada, lost-luggage

Here is what happened

Flying from Atlanta, US to Amman, Jordan through Air Canada

Having an extra bag, Air Canada charged me $100 for the extra bag

in the way to the airplane they asked if they can take one of the carry-on bags to the luggage, we agreed and that bag was taken.

Arrived to Amman airport and 2 bags missing (one is the extra bag was in the baggage) and the other is carry-on that was taken to the luggage..

We have a wedding to attend and all the clothes are in that missing bag and other accessories in the other one..

what is my right and will be compensated for the missing bags

if they found them and return them, am I entitled to be compensated for the delay (1 week so far)?

- Note : no travel insurance

Comment: Was this a nonstop flight, a flight with one or more stops but no change of aircraft, or a flight that involved changing planes?

Comment: Atlanta to Amman on Air Canada - almost certainly with a stop.

Comment: @shoover yea there was a stop in Toronto and Frankfort

Comment: Probably not AC as operating carrier all the way, though, but it shouldn't matter which you make the claim to as any airline that "participated in the carriage of the passenger" must follow your claim to conclusion. https://www.iata.org/contentassets/e7a533819be440edbb1e49da96e0f2a8/guidance-document-on-baggage-standards-for-interline.pdf section 10, Mishandled Baggage. Hmm... I guess that should be an answer.

Comment: Yes @shoover, please post as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The normal process is this:

1. You file a report at the airport your luggage is delayed.
2. You buy everything you need in the interim and keep the receipts meticulously and file them with the airline ASAP. ( [Air Canada](https://www.aircanada.com/ca/en/aco/home/plan/baggage/delayed-damaged-baggage.html) )
3. Review airline policies whether any additional steps are required. AC on the link mentions something at three days, for example.
4. After 21 days or when the airline admits the bag is lost, you initiate a process for compensation of the contents.
5. Within two years you sue the airline if they don't pay.

For 2+3 *together* the responsibility of the airline is 1,288 Special Drawing Rights (which is approximately $2,400 CAD) per passenger.

A useful website can be found on https://airpassengerrights.ca/en/practical-guides/baggage/lost

There's also the non-trivial question of who is responsible in the first place but this should've been made clear at the airport when you reported. If not, that'll be a bear to untangle.

1. What were the flight numbers you've flown?
2. What is the first three digits of the reservation number? It should be 13 or 14 digits and most likely starts with 014 or 020 or *maybe* 016.